# Active buttons replacing img-src inside currently active button and reverse src when not active

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, button

I have 8 active buttons and I want to change the img-src on the currently active button and reverse the src when it's not active anymore. I'm bad at JS and I can't figure it out.

All the inactive images have the ending "_grey.png" and the active ones should be "_blue.png".

html:

```
<div id="worldfilter">
    <button class="wf-btn active"><img src="world_blue.png"> Welt </button>
    <button class="wf-btn"><img src="europe_grey.png"></button>
    <button class="wf-btn"><img src="north_america_grey.png"></button>
    <button class="wf-btn"><img src="south_america_grey.png"></button>
    <button class="wf-btn"><img src="africa_grey.png"></button>
    <button class="wf-btn"><img src="orient_grey.png"></button>
    <button class="wf-btn"><img src="asia_grey.png"></button>
    <button class="wf-btn"><img src="oceania_grey.png"></button>
  </div>
```

js:

```
//Worldfilter button
// Get the container element
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("worldfilter");

// Get all buttons with class="wf-btn" inside the container
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("wf-btn");

// Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this (i commented the code).

```js
$('.wf-btn').click(function() {
  $('.wf-btn').removeClass('active');  // we remove class for all btn
  $(this).addClass('active');  // we add class to the current btn
  
  // we set all img src btn with _blue.png to _grey.png
  $('.wf-btn').each(function() { 
    var SRCLoop = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    
    if (SRCLoop.substr(SRCLoop.length-9) == '_blue.png') {
     var newSRCLoop = SRCLoop.replace('_blue.png','');
     $(this).find('img').attr('src', newSRCLoop + '_grey.png');
    }
  });

  var btnSRC = $(this).find('img').attr('src'); // we get the src of the current img btn
  
  // we change src img btn
  if (btnSRC.substr(btnSRC.length-9) != '_blue.png') {
   var newSRC = btnSRC.replace('_grey.png','');
   $(this).find('img').attr('src', newSRC + '_blue.png'); 
  } else {
   var newSRC = btnSRC.replace('_blue.png','');
   $(this).find('img').attr('src', newSRC + '_grey.png');   
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="worldfilter">
    <button class="wf-btn active"><img src="world_blue.png"> Welt </button>
    <button class="wf-btn"><img src="europe_grey.png"></button>
    <button class="wf-btn"><img src="north_america_grey.png"></button>
    <button class="wf-btn"><img src="south_america_grey.png"></button>
    <button class="wf-btn"><img src="africa_grey.png"></button>
    <button class="wf-btn"><img src="orient_grey.png"></button>
    <button class="wf-btn"><img src="asia_grey.png"></button>
    <button class="wf-btn"><img src="oceania_grey.png"></button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="worldfilter">
    <button onclick="make_active(this);" class="wf-btn active"><img src="img/blue.png"> Welt </button>
    <button onclick="make_active(this);" class="wf-btn"><img src="img/grey.png"></button>
    <button onclick="make_active(this);" class="wf-btn"><img src="img/grey.png"></button>
    <button onclick="make_active(this);"class="wf-btn"><img src="img/grey.png"></button>
    <button onclick="make_active(this);"class="wf-btn"><img src="img/grey.png"></button>
    <button onclick="make_active(this);"class="wf-btn"><img src="img/grey.png"></button>
    <button onclick="make_active(this);"class="wf-btn"><img src="img/grey.png"></button>
    <button onclick="make_active(this);" class="wf-btn"><img src="img/grey.png"></button>
  </div>
<style>
    img{
        max-width:50px;
    }
</style>
<script>
function make_active(btn){
    for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName("wf-btn").length;i++){
        document.getElementsByClassName("wf-btn")[i].children[0].setAttribute("src","img/grey.png");
        
    }
    btn.children[0].setAttribute("src","img/blue.png");
    
}
</script>
```